# Installing pytorch is not the version I want

Tags: docker, pytorch

```
# Use Nvidia CUDA base image
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu22.04 as base

# Prevents prompts from packages asking for user input during installation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Prefer binary wheels over source distributions for faster pip installations
ENV PIP_PREFER_BINARY=1
# Ensures output from python is printed immediately to the terminal without buffering
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 

# Install Python, git and other necessary tools
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3.10 \
    python3-pip \
    git \
    wget \
    libgl-dev \
    python3-opencv \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    ffmpeg

# Clean up to reduce image size
RUN apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Install ComfyUI dependencies
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir xformers==0.0.21 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple

# Install runpod
RUN pip3 install runpod requests -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple

# Go back to the root
WORKDIR /

# Add the start and the handler
ADD src/start.sh src/rp_handler.py test_input.json ./
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

# Start the container
CMD /start.sh
```

During the installation, I get an error message, see below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7rz3.png)

After installing, I started the container and used `torch.__version__` to check the version number and got 2.0.1

I should get pytorch version number 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://dev-discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-release-2-1-2-final-rc-is-available/1708), have you tried modifying this lines :

```
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple \
&& pip3 install --no-cache-dir xformers==0.0.21 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```

to :

```
RUN pip3 install torch==2.1.2 torchvision==0.16.2 torchaudio==2.1.2 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/test/cu118
&& pip3 install --no-cache-dir xformers==0.0.21 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```